# Face to face video chat using openTok (tokbox)

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

I build a kind of a social network where the users can chat with each other.
Only private chats, not rooms or groups or anything like this.

I want to to add a feature to the chat - video chat.

And I find openTok (tokbox).
I read alot from thier manual but I can't make it work.

I started in something simple.

I opend in two different computers url with this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.0/js/TB.min.js" ></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var apiKey    = **myApiKey**;
          var sessionId = **sessionId **;
          var token     = **token**;

          function sessionConnectedHandler (event) {
             session.publish( publisher );
             subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
          }
          function subscribeToStreams(streams) {
            for (var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
                var stream = streams[i];
                if (stream.connection.connectionId 
                       != session.connection.connectionId) {
                    session.subscribe(stream);
                }
            }
          }
          function streamCreatedHandler(event) {
            subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
          }

          var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey);
          var session   = TB.initSession(sessionId);

          session.connect(apiKey, token);
          session.addEventListener("sessionConnected", 
                                   sessionConnectedHandler);

          session.addEventListener("streamCreated", 
                                   streamCreatedHandler);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course I changed  **myApiKey**, **sessionId**, **token** to my details from my account.

The problem is that In every page I can see myself, buy the partner window doesn't stop loading...

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a JSfiddle of this?

Answer (score 2):

In your `sessionConnectedHandler()`, you have to remove `publisher` parameter, then it works fine... Somewhat look like this:

```
function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
  subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
  session.publish();
}
```